# Bluemixで.pyプログラムからdashDBに接続したいです

Tags: python, bluemix

pythonのアプリケーションのサービスを立ち上げました。
Test.pyというプログラムを書いているのですが、dashDBに接続して、SQLを実行したいです。
ちなみにですが、Bluemixではないところでは動いています。
その時は、以下のようにしています。

```
dsn = 'sqldb' # ODBC User Dataset SQLDB definition required
usr = 'dash013754'
psw = 'XXXXXXXXXXX'
try:
    conn = ibm_db.connect(dsn,usr,psw)
except:     
    print "no connection:", ibm_db.conn_errormsg()
else:
    print "The connection was successful" 

def selectSQLDB():
    now = datetime.datetime.today()
        print now
    sql = "SELECT NAME FROM SYSIBM.SYTABLES"
    stmt = ibm_db.prepare(conn, sql)
    body = "body of Tweet"
    ibm_db.bind_param(stmt, 1, body)
    try:
        ibm_db.execute(stmt)        
#       stmt = ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn, sql)     
    except:
        print "Transaction couldn't be completed:" , ibm_db.stmt_errormsg()
        print stmt
        print sql
    else:
        print "Transaction complete."
```

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 他で動いているということは、コードはあっているのでしょう。データ依存の問題だとしたらdsn, usr, psw、ODBCの設定をみるしかないのでは？エラーメッセージは？

Answer (score 1):

Bluemixのドキュメントページに、dashDBに接続するコードスニペットが掲載されています。
右上の言語選択プルダウンメニューでPythonを選択してください。

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/dashDB/index.html#dashDB

dashDB接続のための資格情報は変更される可能性がありますので、ハードコードするのではなく、上記URLの例のように環境変数 VCAP_SERVICES から取得することが推奨されています。

実際に動かして確かめたいという場合は、下記URLのサンプルをお使いください。
https://hub.jazz.net/project/ibmdatabase/dashDB/overview#https://hub.jazz.net/git/ibmdatabase%252FdashDB/list/master/samples/dashDBPython